# CSS: place div on the right of float:right

Tags: css, positioning, css-float

Hi stack overflow community. I have 2 **dynamic** divs that I want to float right inside a container. But I want the last div on the HTML to be more on the right than the first one. My problem is that I can't change the HTML, only CSS.

This will be used for navigation between pages, so I can have both divs visible or only one. Even if I only have one div, it has to be aligned to the right of the container (that's why I wanted to use floats).

Here's a jsfiddle for you to understand better: http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/yVCDZ/1/

I want "Next" to appear after "Previous". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of float, use `display:inline-block;` and set the container's `text-align:right;`

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mestekweb/yVCDZ/2/

That should get you started, at least.

ps - You will probably have problems with IE <8. I can offer some assistance there as well, if you need.

Comment: display:inline-block; is the way to go.

Comment: This seems to work great. What kind of problems will I have with IE<8?

Comment: IE7 and earlier don't recognize inline-block. You can use `display:inline;` in this case.  You'll probably also have to get the hasLayout property set using something like `zoom:1;`

Here's a fiddle with the IE7 hack.  Maybe not the best way, but it's what I've got for now. http://jsfiddle.net/mestekweb/yVCDZ/10/

Answer (score 0):

As per i understand may be that's you want. You can use **direction** with **display:inline-block;**

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/yVCDZ/3/

& there is an other alternative which work in all browsers

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/yVCDZ/8/

Answer (score 0):

Quick update using positioning:

```
#container {
    width:300px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;

}

#previous {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background:gold;
    position: absolute;
    right: 70px;
}

#next {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background:lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```